Adding borders to 2D plot in ggplot2
the displayed code produces the following plot with ggplot2:
plot_DK <- ggplot(coordinate_grid, aes(coordinate_east, coordinate_north, fill = model1_predictions)) +
           geom_tile() +
           labs(x = "", y = "") +
           scico::scale_fill_scico(palette = "vik") +
           theme(axis.text = element_blank())


However, in reality my data frame coordinate_grid also contains a column indicating the region that each point belongs to. I would ideally like to add this information to the plot such that each collection of points belonging to a particular region is surrounded by a border as shown in the hand-drawn example below. Does anyone know if this is possible?


I think what you are trying to do is go from your grid of region values to polygons, which you could do with terra::as.polygons with a bit of manipulation of your data. Could you redo your maps with fill=region (or whatever the column name is) which should show  a map of the regions in solid colours...

Alternatively, if your regions are the five admin regions of Denmark ("Hovedstaden", "Midtjylland", "Nordjylland", "Sjælland", "Syddanmark") then you can get a boundary file from the GADM project or some other online source and add it to your plot as a geom_sf layer.

If you can let us know if these are standard boundaries available online then I'll post an answer - which I've done - that uses those boundaries via geom_sf (which you should always consider when making geographic maps).

If you have your boundaries file, and it contains your region names, we can use geom_sf and geom_sf_text
First, assume the following is your plot
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

NC_counties <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) 

p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = NC_counties, aes(fill = AREA),  linewidth = 0)
p1


We'll create some regions. And select the region we want to highlight
NC_regions <- NC_counties %>%
  mutate(group = str_c("group ", unlist(map(1:5, ~ rep(.x, 20))))) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise() %>%
  st_union(by_feature = TRUE)

NC_regions_selection <- NC_regions[1,]

We'll add to our existing plot the boundaries for our regions, then the boundary for our selected region in red, and lastly the names of all the regions.
p1 +
  geom_sf(data = NC_regions, fill = "NA", color = "black") +
  geom_sf(data = NC_regions_selection, fill = NA, color = "red") +
    geom_sf_text(data = NC_regions, aes(label = group))


Created on 2024-07-20 with reprex v2.1.1
